# Page changes not reflected with lighttpd

Tags: php, codeigniter, lighttpd

I switched from apache to lighttpd. Setup was successful with fasCGI and php now running. I also have the CodeIgniter framework running.

So I `scp` my project to document Root. Everything works except any changes that I make in file are not reflected in the application. Looks like there's some sort of cacheing mechanism. Also, vi keeps saying "Incomplete last line" for every file (mac to debian file transfer) that I have in the application. I clreaed my browser-side cache, restarted the server, all the basic stuff... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. just flushed the lighttpd cache. That worked. For some reason I had I messed up this  line while configuring 
`

> static-file.exclude-extensions = (  ".pl", ".fcgi" )

` (in the config file) as you can see, I forgot to put in the .php file extension.